# Abstract method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import abc

class SetterGetter(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def set_val(self, inp):
        return

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_val(self):
        return

class TryAbsMethod(SetterGetter):
    def get_val(self):
        return self.inp

    def set_valz(self, inp):
        self.inp = inp

a = TryAbsMethod()
print(a)
```

As per tutorial, I was expecting excption from above code but instead I got output from python which is strange, Can someone please explain me why?

### Output got

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/murtuza/MyCodes/abstract.py
<__main__.TryAbsMethod object at 0x7f93ba8ab048>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Exception Which is expected

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class TryAbsMethod with abstract method set_val
```

Comment: Which tutorial is it that you're using?

Comment: @Evert: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040057.do#tab_02_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Python 3.x. In Python 3.x, metaclass declaring syntax is changed.

```
class SetterGetter(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):  # <---
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def set_val(self, inp):
        return

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_val(self):
        return
```

See [Customizing class creation - Data model - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), [PEP3115 - Metaclasses in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/)

Comment: @RajeshChoudhary, Please post a question, instead of commenting on irrelevant answers.

Comment: this is my question please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519620/how-to-scrape-pages-which-have-lazy-loading