# How to scrape pages which have lazy loading

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Here is the code which i used for parsing of web page.I did it in rails console.But i am not getting any output in my rails console.The site which i want to scrape is having lazy loading

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = 1
while true
  url =  "http://www.justdial.com/functions"+"/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Delhi+%2F+NCR&search=Pandits"+"&where=Delhi+Cantt&catid=1195&psearch=&prid=&page=#{page}"


  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc.at_css('#ajax').text)
  d = doc.css(".rslwrp")
  d.each do |t|
     puts t.css(".jrcw").text
     puts t.css("span.jcn").text
     puts t.css(".jaid").text
     puts t.css(".estd").text
    page+=1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Switch pure HTTP scraping to some tool which supports javascript evaluation, such as Capybara (with [proper driver](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver) selected). This can be slow, since you're running headless browser under the hood plus you'll have to set some timeouts or figure another way to make sure the blocks of text you're interested in are loaded before you start any scraping.
2. Second option is to use Web Developer console and figure out how those blocks of text are loaded (which AJAX calls, their parameters and etc.) and implement them in your scraper. This is more advanced approach, but more performant, since you won't make any extra work, like you've done in option 1.

Have a nice day!

UPDATE:

Your code above doesn't work, because the response is HTML code wrapped in JSON object, while you're trying to parse it as a raw HTML. It looks like this:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "msg": "request successful",
  "paidDocIds": "some ids here",
  "itemStartIndex": 20,
  "lastPageNum": 50,
  "markup": 'LOTS AND LOTS AND LOTS OF MARKUP'
}
```

What you need is unwrap JSON and then parse as HTML:

```
require 'json' 

json = JSON.parse(open(url).read) # make sure you check http errors here
html = json['markup'] # can this field be empty? check for the json['error'] field
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html) # parse as you like
```

I'd also [advise you against](http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html) using `open-uri` since your code may become vulnerable if you use dynamic urls because of the way `open-uri` works (read the linked article for the details) and use good and more feature-wise libraries such as [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

UPDATE 2: Minimal working script for me:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Delhi+%2F+NCR&search=Pandits&where=Delhi+Cantt&catid=1195&psearch=&prid=&page=2'

json = JSON.parse(open(url).read) # make sure you check http errors here
html = json['markup'] # can this field be empty? check for the json['error'] field
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html) # parse as you like
puts doc.at_css('#newphoto10').attr('title')
# => Dr Raaj Batra Lal Kitab Expert in East Patel Nagar, Delhi
```

Comment: i checked it in console...all ajax call have same parameter except page no......only thing which changes is page no & i already put page no in placeholder & put it in loop

Comment: If you open this url in a browser: `http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Delhi+%2F+NCR&search=Pandits&where=Delhi+Cantt&catid=1195&psearch=&prid=&page=2` it shows some JSON response, seems to be working fine, isn't it?

Comment: my actual url is this http://www.justdial.com/Delhi-NCR/Pandits-%3Cnear%3E-delhi/ct-1195  url which i mentioned in my question i got it from console

Comment: @RajeshChoudhary please, mark the post as a solution, if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this site has blocked you for you continuous scraping? Try to use other ip or some proxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89372/discussion-between-alexey-shein-and-rajesh-choudhary).

Comment: @AlexeyShein, "please, mark the post as a solution, if it solves your problem. Thanks!" We're not here to gather points, we're here to help the community. Please don't troll for votes or being the selected answer. It's considered very bad form. Instead, make sure your answer is thorough and correct and the votes and selections will happen.